# How do I install pg routing to an existing postgresql 9.1 database

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-12.04, postgresql-9.1, pgrouting

I installed **postgresql 9.1.12** using `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1 postgresql-9.1-contrib postgresql-9.1-postgis` and created databse "**mydb**". Then extended the **mydb** using

```
psql -h localhost -d mydb -U abc -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql

psql -h localhost -d mydb -U abc -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-1.5/spatial_ref_sys.sql
```

I want to install pg routing to "mydb" in my **ubuntu 12.04** machine.
I tried this `psql mydb -c "create extension pgrouting"` but got error

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/pgrouting.control": No such file or directory
```

Then downloaded **pgrouting-1.05.tar.gz** from http://pgrouting.org/download.html but don't know how to install to an existing db.

Comment: Why are you installing an outdated and unsupported version? (And pgRouting 1.x is also deprecated, but the installation is documented here: http://pgrouting.org/docs/1.x/install.html).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok...so i need to create a new database,right?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name pls suggest me pgrouting version..which will be compatable with posrgresql 9.1